# Azure Search - return only certain number of words from a field

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We have a database that stores news stories from many websites.  The entire text of each article is stored in one field of unstructured data as nvarcharmax.  Our clients query on a person's name to see if they appear anywhere in any of our articles.  But in order for us to be compliant with requirements in our industry, as well as not infringe on any copyrights, we're only allowed to return the 25 words which surround that person's name that was queried on.  Along with that we give the client the URL of the article and they can take it from there.

Is this something that can be accomplished in Azure Search?  The ability to only display a subset of words from the field which is being queried on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hit highlighting feature in Azure Search. Please see highlight= parameter in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents.

Azure Search returns up to five text fragments, which are usually sentences, that contains the search hits per field. It currently does not allow you to configure the size of the window/fragment so you can't get a specific number of words surrounding the search terms.